# How to order room entity by last reply time in a chat application?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am designing a chat application's database schema in Apache Cassandra and I couldn't wrap my head around this.

Here's my schema so far:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
  user_id bigint,
  nickname text,
  email text,
  chat_rooms set<timeuuid>,
  PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE rooms(
  room_id timeuuid,
  creation_date timestamp,
  creator_id bigint,
  participants set<bigint>,
  PRIMARY KEY(room_id)
);￼

CREATE TABLE messages(
  message_id timeuuid,
  room_id timeuuid,
  author_id bigint,
  time_bucket int,
  content text,
  PRIMARY KEY((room_id, time_bucket), message_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (message_id DESC);
```

I would like to get a list of room by a user's id ordered by last reply time, similar to Facebook Messenger and Telegram.

I was thinking adding a new column `last_reply_time` to `rooms`, use it as clustering key and update that when there is new message in the room. However it is impossible to update clustering key value in Cassandra. How should I go about modelling this?

I have looked at the [KillrChat example](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/getting-started-killrchat-example-data-model-messaging) and [Discord's wonderful piece](https://blog.discordapp.com/how-discord-stores-billions-of-messages-7fa6ec7ee4c7) on their Cassandra implementation but they did not mention anything related to my issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a table like this

```
create table test (
   creator_id bigint ,
   room_id timeuuid ,
   last_reply_time timestamp,
   primary KEY ((creator_id), room_id))
with CLUSTERING ORDER BY
   (room_id ASC );
```

and you could insert into it all last_reply_time and select your data with

```
select * from test where creator_id = ? and room_id = ?
```

You will do only inserts that will update the same entry in the database, since you will have the same creator_id and room_id.

Comment: If you remove the `last_reply_time` from clustering then you don't need to delete ever, and then you can just iterate down without room_id in select. Providing a user doesnt have thousands of rooms they are in it wont be expensive to just walk the resultset into memory and sort. If they get too big can use a heap or priorityqueue as walking resultset so never exceed a limit in memory.